# Mouse over the image with magnifying glass in html

Tags: javascript, php, html

I added a magnifying glass for images in my webpage using the following instruction:
https://www.w3schools.com/howto/howto_js_image_magnifier_glass.asp

The magnified box stays on the image even if the mouse is not over it. How can I revise this in a way that the magnifying glass appears only when the mouse is over it?

Thanks,

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do this all in CSS using hover, no need for javascript copy the style sheet from below.

```
<style>
* {box-sizing: border-box;}
.img-magnifier-container {
  position:relative;
  cursor:none;
}
.img-magnifier-container:hover .img-magnifier-glass {
  position: absolute;
  border: 3px solid #000;
  border-radius: 50%;
  cursor: none;
  /*Set the size of the magnifier glass:*/
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  display:block;
}
.img-magnifier-glass {
  display:none;
}

</style>
```

Comment: Hi, thank you for the simple solution. It really works!
I have another question: Is it possible to use magnifier simultaneously on lets say 4 images? I want to zoom in 4 images in the same region of them. I need this for comparison between images.

Comment: I'm unsure if it will work with the way the code is currently set up and it may take more work. Theoretically you can define backgroundPosition globally then pass that value through a modified version of magnify on other images without the move magnifier or get cursor.

Answer (score 1):

In HTML, there is an event called onmouseleave. You could make the element call a javascript function when your mouse leaves the image.
Here's the link for more information: https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/event_onmouseleave.asp
Here's the basics of it:
    `onmouseleave="functionName()"`

Comment: I did this:

     `<script>
magnify("myimage", 3);

function normalImg(x) {
    x.style.width = "100%";
}
</script>

<div class="img-magnifier-container">
  <img id="myimage" onmouseleave="normalImg(this)" src="img_fjords.jpg" width="100%">
</div>`

But it didn't work. Is there any problemin above code?

Comment: what does normalImg do?

Comment: Also, you could just have a Boolean called display and pass it false as a parameter

Comment: normalImage should cancel the magnification. So it is just resizing the image to 100% of its size

Comment: Here is the link to that code. See if you can do it?
https://www.w3schools.com/howto/tryit.asp?filename=tryhow_js_image_magnifier_glass

Comment: ah yes, MMallette has a good point, you can modify the state of the display.

Answer (score 1):

You need to add a onmouseout event to the magnifying glass div and an id to identify it, like this:

```
  glass = document.createElement("DIV");
  glass.id="glassId";
  glass.setAttribute("onmouseout", "hide()");
```

Then add a show and hide function like this:

```
function hide(){
    glass = document.getElementById("glassId").style.display = "none";
}
function show(){
    glass = document.getElementById("glassId").style.display = "block";
}
```

Finally add the mouseover event to the image itself:

```
onmouseover="show()"
```

This will then hide the glass when the mouse leaves the glass (not the image) and show it when the mouse goes back into the image.

Comment: I believe this should also work. But MMallette's solution was much easier in my case. Thank you.